# error C2248: 'CObject::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class, visual-c++, mfc, cfiledialog

I have implemented this MFC class.(Note that what is written here is just a part of my class)
here is the file FilesWorkFlow.h

```
#pragma once


// FilesWorkFlow

class FilesWorkFlow : public CWnd
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(FilesWorkFlow)

public:
    FilesWorkFlow();
    virtual ~FilesWorkFlow();
    CString GetPath();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
private:
    wchar_t* lpszFilter;

};
```

and here is the file FilesWorkFlow.cpp

```
// FilesWorkFlow.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "InitialJobProject2.h"
#include "FilesWorkFlow.h"


// FilesWorkFlow

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(FilesWorkFlow, CWnd)

FilesWorkFlow::FilesWorkFlow()
{
    lpszFilter = _T("JPEG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|")
    _T("TIFF Files (*.tif)|*.tif|")_T("PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|")_T("Bitmap Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|");
}

FilesWorkFlow::~FilesWorkFlow()
{
}

CString FilesWorkFlow::GetPath()
{
    CFileDialog dlgFile = CFileDialog(true,0,0,OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_HIDEREADONLY,lpszFilter,0,0,true);
    if (dlgFile.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        CString pathname = dlgFile.GetPathName();
        return pathname;
    }
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(FilesWorkFlow, CWnd)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()



// FilesWorkFlow message handlers
```

and in the file InitialJobProject2Dlg.h that is the header of the class related to my Dialog window and is derived from the class CDialogEx, I have this code:

```
#include "FilesWorkFlow.h" 
......
private:
CWndResizer m_resizer;
FilesWorkFlow m_filesWorkFlow;
```

and finally this is what is in file FilesWorkFlow.cpp

```
void CInitialJobProject2Dlg::OnBnClickedBtnbrowse()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    m_filesWorkFlow = FilesWorkFlow();
    CString filepath = m_filesWorkFlow.GetPath();
}
```

I can't find the reason for the error specified?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a CFileDialog to a CFileDialog, which is not a supported operation. Initialize dlgFile this way:

```
CFileDialog dlgFile(...);
```